Flutter Doctor: JAVA_HOME set correctly but still getting 'Cannot execute /usr/bin/java/bin/java' error
I'm setting up Flutter development on Ubuntu 24.04. I installed Android Studio, Java, and the Android SDK. However, flutter doctor keeps throwing the error:
Cannot execute /usr/bin/java/bin/java to determine the version
Even though JAVA_HOME is set correctly to the JetBrains Runtime (JBR) bundled with Android Studio.

What I’ve Tried

Installed Android Studio and Java.
Set JAVA_HOME to JBR:

export JAVA_HOME=/home/ganesh-kumar/Programs/android-studio-2024.2.1.11-linux/android-studio/jbr
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH


Verified the Java setup:

ganesh-kumar@gk:~$ which java
/home/ganesh-kumar/Programs/android-studio-2024.2.1.11-linux/android-studio/jbr/bin/java

ganesh-kumar@gk:~$ java -version
openjdk version "21.0.3" 2024-04-16


Reinstalled the Android SDK and cmdline-tools.

Despite this, flutter doctor still shows:
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/bin/java
Environment
OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Flutter Version: 3.24.3
Android Studio Version: 2024.2.1.11
Java Version: openjdk version "21.0.3"

Environment
OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Flutter Version: 3.24.3
Android Studio Version: 2024.2.1.11
Java Version: openjdk version "21.0.3"

How can I resolve this issue so that flutter doctor recognizes my JAVA_HOME setup correctly? Is there something wrong with the JetBrains Runtime, or is additional configuration required for the Android SDK?
I'm setting up Flutter development on Ubuntu 24.04. I installed Android Studio, Java, and the Android SDK. However, flutter doctor keeps throwing the error:
Cannot execute /usr/bin/java/bin/java to determine the version
Even though JAVA_HOME is set correctly to the JetBrains Runtime (JBR) bundled with Android Studio.

Since you're using Java SDK 21, have you replace the directory that is added in JAVA_HOME with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21?

I am on linux.
I've added JAVA_HOME with /home/ganesh-kumar/Programs/android-studio-2024.2.1.11-linux/android-studio/jbr
This is Android studio's java bundled.

Okay, I will learn Linux next time to understand its environment.

can you post exact flutter doctor log so i can  help you
